# clearcase to git with gradle

Tags: github, clearcase

I have a spring application in ClearCase repo currently with 3 folders architecture such as `util`, `web` and `EAR` but I need to migrate it to Git.

So how this architecture to be maintained with gradle, as I don't want to change my code

Answer (score 1):

If your current working tree is working with graddle, simply import it in a new git repo from your snapshot view:

```
cd /path/to/snapshot/view
git init .
touch .gitignore
```

Add the files/folder you don't need in a git repo.
See for instance [`Gradle.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Gradle.gitignore)

```
git add .
git commit -m "My first commit"
```

That won't import the *full* history (you still can see it through ClearCase), but you will then be able to push that git repo to a remote one, and start working with Git from there.